# How can I convert this Unity code to MonoGame code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, xamarin, monogame

I don't know how to use PlayFab in a MonoGame project. I have read some PlayFab tutorials, but they are all for Unity and I think that it's not possible to use the Unity code samples with MonoGame, because I always get error messages.

From this line of code.

```
PlayFabClientAPI.GetUserInventoryAsync(new GetUserInventoryRequest(), OnGetUserInventoryRequest, OnPlayFabInventoryError);
```

I get the error messages here:

> Error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to
>   'object'
>
> Error CS1503: Argument 3: cannot convert from 'method group' to
>   'Dictionary'

Something is wrong with "OnGetUserInventoryRequest, OnPlayFabInventoryError", but I don't know what I could change.

What can I change so that this code works with MonoGame?

[image]

https://api.playfab.com/documentation/client/method/GetUserInventory

**Sample Code**

```
public void GetInventoryList()
{
    PlayFabClientAPI.GetUserInventoryAsync(new GetUserInventoryRequest(), OnGetUserInventoryRequest, OnPlayFabInventoryError);
}
public void OnGetUserInventoryRequest(GetUserInventoryResult result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.VirtualCurrency);
}

public void OnPlayFabInventoryError(PlayFabError result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
}
```

**EDIT:**

I get a new error message if I want to use the value of VirtualCurrency. I don't know how to get the value of VirtualCurrency, what am I doing wrong?

```
private async Task GetInventoryList()
{
    var result = await PlayFabClientAPI.GetUserInventoryAsync(new GetUserInventoryRequest());

    int CurrentAmount = result.Result.VirtualCurrency;
}
```

> Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary' to 'int'

[image]

Comment: what is the method signature for GetUserInventoryAsync?

Comment: I added a picture. Do you mean this with method signature for GetUserInventoryAsync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's pretty obvious if you look at the method signature:

```
GetUserInventoryAsync(GetUserInventoryRequest request, object customData = null, Dictionary<string,string> extraHeaders = null)
```

the last 2 parameters are optional, and they are not callback methods

Comment: Thank you. I have another question about the usage of the request. I need the value of VirtualCurrency, but I don't know how to get the value because it's not an integer. How can I get the value of VirtualCurrency?

Comment: VirtualCurrency is a dictionary, so you have to supply a key to get a value - `int CurrentAmount = result.Result.VirtualCurrency["GD"];`  I have no idea what the valid values for the key (CurrencyCode) are, you'll need to figure that out.

Comment: CurrencyCode is the two letter code of my virtual currency in PlayFab. Thank you, it works now ;)